# Android marshmallow WifiManager leaking IntentReceiver

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, wifimanager, android-6.0.1-marshmallow

Here's the scenario, I have a `LoginActivity` that makes use of the `WifiManager` to obtain the **IP address** like this:

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager)getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
String ipAddress = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo().getIpAddress();
```

I **do not** register any receiver to receive any WiFi updates. I use the `WifiManager` to obtain the IP Address **only and nothing else**.

Now when I complete login, I call `finish()` in `LoginActivity` and start `SplashActivity` and that's when I see the following log in console:

> LoginActivity has leaked IntentReceiver android.net.wifi.WifiManager
>   that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to
>   unregisterReceiver()?

And I get this log **only on** marshmallow. This does not happen on <6.0 devices ever. Also on marshmallow, the app never crashes but I see this log every time.

If anyone can explain this behaviour?

Comment: Have you solved this issue? I'm facing the same problem. Please update your question if you solved this. Thanks.

Comment: @VajiraLasantha No, I haven't. Still waiting for someone to answer.

Comment: @VajiraLasantha Check out Kai's answer below and let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same error, but only when running in debug for some reason.

Adding: `getApplicationContext()` fixed the issue for me. (Although I'm not entirely sure why?)

```
WifiManager wifi_manager = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
```

After doing a bit more research it looks like when you transition from one activity to the other the context no longer exists.

> getApplicationContext() - Returns the context for all activities running in application.
>
> getContext() - Returns the context view only current running activity.

So it's probably best use getApplicationContext() for anything that should survive for the lifetime of your app.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I tested this and there was no exception in the logs. An explanation would've been great but I am gonna anyway upvote and accept the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, I did a bit more research and updated my answer.

Comment: Yes, it makes sense. But still it's a little bit weird to get leaked `IntentReceiver` for this reason. And also not to forget, this behaviour is only on 6.0+ devices. For <6.0 devices, `getContext()` works just fine.